# Detect what page was linked-from

Tags: links

Is there a Wordpress way of detecting which post or page on the site you linked-from?

The aim is to display custom content, in this case a category archive grid at the bottom of the current page, depending on which page you were last on.

If not a directly Wordpress way, then a best-practices php way of doing this, like an easily-accessible place in the database?

Comment: I don't know any wordpress way but you can have a url variable ie http://mydomain.com/a-page/?ref=5 where 5 is the ID of the post/page of the previous page

Comment: That could work. Something like: `$genre_url = add_query_arg('genre', $term->slug, get_permalink());`

Comment: Or $_SESSION or, having just discovered it, the 3rd party $wp_session library: http://eamann.com/tech/introducing-wp_session/

Comment: With sessions you have to save every time the current page where the user is and also handle expired sessions etc. I think with urls it would be easier as this would be for everyone and not specifically to some kind of users. For the links better to add a filter 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link

Answer (score 0):

To encode the URLs on the source page, in this case 'home':

```
function append_query_string( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        $url = add_query_arg( 'source', 'home', $url );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 3 );
```

This adds `?source=home` to the end of post link URLs on the home page.

To decode the URL on the target page ie. create a variable with 'home' detected as its value in this example:

```
$posturl =  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
parse_str( parse_url( $posturl, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $get_args);
$source = $get_args['source'];
```

*Thanks to Laxmana for the suggestion.*